# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u5347' in position 68: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python. I read data from SQL Server and then write the data into a csv file. The table row has both number, string and datetime values. I tried different ways to write the data. For example,

```
#method 1
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=["colummn"])

df.to_csv('list.csv', index=False)*  

#method 2
import csv

fl = open('OnlineplayDatabase.csv', 'w')

writer = csv.writer(fl)

for row in table:

    writer.writerow(row)

fl.close()
```

Both methods are normally working. But when some rows contain Chinese characters (see example below), I received an encoding error. The error message says:

```
codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

#Error Code   
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u5347' in position 68: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried to encode the fields in the row using utf-8. But some of the fields are numbers.

Your help is highly appreciated!

```
('120.239.9.116  ',
 'gyandroid ',
 4,
 9,
 'Dalvik/1.6.0(Linux;U;Android4.4.2;升级版Build/KVT49L)                                                                      datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 11, 20, 54, 19),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 11, 20, 56, 53),
 11521.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this for method #2:

```
#method 2
import csv

fl = open('OnlineplayDatabase.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') #set the encoding to utf8
writer = csv.writer(fl)

for row in table:
    writer.writerow(row)

fl.close()
```

Also take a look at this - http://www.pgbovine.net/unicode-python-errors.htm

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error again. This is happening because somewhere in your dataframe there are words that begin with `\u`. You need to get rid of that. See if this works. Use the `remove_u` function below to get rid of the `\u`.

```
def remove_u(word):
    word_u = (word.encode('unicode-escape')).decode("utf-8", "strict")
    if r'\u' in word_u: 
        # print(True)
        return word_u.split('\\u')[1]
    return word

df.loc[:, 'colummn'] = df['colummn'].apply(func = remove_u)
```

Once you have updated the dataframe, try writing it out again.

**EDIT**

I am assuming your column is composed of individual words. If your column has strings instead use the modified version of the `remove_u`

```
def remove_u(input_string):
    words = input_string.split()
    words_u = [(word.encode('unicode-escape')).decode("utf-8", "strict") for word in words]
    words_u = [word_u.split('\\u')[1] if r'\u' in word_u else word_u for word_u in words_u]
    # print(words_u)
    return ' '.join(words_u)
```